# In Microsoft Word 2013 Cursor Disappears Periodically

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, intel-graphics

I am seeing an issue with Microsoft Word 2013, where the text insertion cursor disappears. That is, when typing the vertical blinking cursor isn't visible. Clicking with the mouse can cause it to be displayed temporarily. Sometimes, disabling **hardware graphics acceleration** can fix the problem for a little while. I've updated the video driver on the system (Intel HD 2500) but to no benefit.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have the 'Hide pointer while typing' option enabled in Mouse settings.

To correct this, do the following:

1. Open Run (Windows Key + R)
2. Type 'control mouse' and press enter
3. Navigate to the 'Pointer Options' tab
4. Uncheck the 'Hide pointer while typing' checkbox

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure that this will help as your suggested setting relates to the mouse cursor and the issue we're facing is to do with the blinking insertion point. It is also, frustratingly, intermittent. It also has only been observed in Word and not (yet?) in Outlook or other applications.

Answer (score 0):

I had problem that curser disappeared as I opened the Word. When I set the Line and Paragraph Spacing (in group of tab, Paragraph) to 2.0, (assuming the default Styles was first frame Normal), the curer showed up. See if this would help.